# Angular - Redux

Tags: angular

пишу такой код чтобы подключить Redux к Angular :

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
});

@NgModule({
  imports: [NgReduxModule, BrowserModule, FormsModule, HeaderModule, ListModule, FormsEditModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, AddPost],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>) {
    ngRedux.provideStore(store);
  }
}
```

после этого ловит такую ошибку :

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppModule: (?)
```

и такую ошибку ловит если задействовать конструктор любого компонента в приложении , даже для обьявления переменной ( constructor(private s: string) { } к примеру)

только ошибка тогда уже будет выглядеть

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for <Имя_компонента>: (?)
```

помогите как решить эту проблему , заранее спасибо!

Comment: забыл добавить , делаю все как в этой документации https://github.com/angular-redux/platform/tree/master/packages/store , библиотека @angular-redux/store

Comment: а зачем вообще использовать пакет у которого 100 звездочек и последний коммит 2 года назад? =) еще по нему вопросы задавать спустя 2 года ))

Comment: достойнная помощь , спасибо

Comment: не за что) какой вопрос - такой и ответ. Воспроизводимый пример ты не привел, _как требуют того правила_. Я попробовал установить этот пакет у себя локально, а он не совместим с Angular даже 8м, так что.... Звыняйте, как говорится